# How can I branch "main" node of a UCM project?

Tags: clearcase, rad

We're using RAD with ClearCase plugin as "ClearCase Explorer Perspective". I need to make a new main version of a java project. For that reason, I want to change main/0 version to ie. main/1. How can I forward version from top-level? I tried to make new project by using "Project Explorer" creating new stream. It required previous baselines. However, when I checkin from this new project stream, it branches from the given baseline version(say 1) like below.

```
main
|
0
|
MyProj1_Integration
|
0
|
1(BL)---MyProj2_Integration
|          |
2          0
           |
           1

I want it to be like:

main
0  ------------------- 1 
|                      |
MyProj1_Integration   MyProj2_Integration
|                      |
0                      0
|                      |
1(BL                   1
|
2
```

When inspecting versions from ClearCase Explorer version numbers are shown like below:

/main/MyProj1_Integration/MyProj2_Integration/1

I expect to see:

/main/MyProj2_Integration/1

Also, I want to include latest versions of files from previous branch to the new branch.
How can I achieve that? Do I need to create a new VOB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/main/0` is only accessible from the '`INITIAL`' baseline.

That means you need to have on your `MyProj2_Integration` an baseline ending with `_INITIAL`.
Only that foundation baseline will branch from /main/0.

Once you have that configuration, you will then be able to make a 'deliver' from '`MyProj1_Integration`' to '`MyProj2_Integration`', in order to get back the latest versions of your first project in the new branch '`MyProj2_Integration`'.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, it is what I want. This problem was described here: http://www.cmcrossroads.com/cgi-bin/cmwiki/view/CM/ClearCaseUnifiedChangeManagement#1_10_What_is_the_Mainline_Projec But there is an overhead for that: "The disadvantage of starting with an empty project every time is that you will deliver the complete contents of a previous project, for every project again. This is an inefficient use of branching since you are duplicating a lot of data. " For that reason, I plan to use cascading projects for small releases and "projects from scratch" for big releases.

Comment: @ilevent: a better solution would be, from that empty project, to add just one file, put a baseline "`0.0.0`", and start all your project streams not from an `_INITIAL` baseline, but from a "`0.0.0`" baseline.