# can't read the foundation baselines?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-ucm

This looks like a serious problem to me. I can't get the foundation baseline info on the integration stream.

Can not view the properties/baselines in `spider1_wells_integration` in clearprojexp tool!

I got the error message:

```
Unable to read the foundation baselines
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you cannot do it from the GUI, try it from the command line (DOS or shell)

```
cd /path/to/your/view
cleartool lsstream -anc -cview # just to check your current stream
cleartool descr -fmt "%[found_bls]CXp" stream:myStream@\myPVob
```

See "[Display Current Baseline with Cleartool](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5897978/display-current-baseline-with-cleartool/5898359#5898359)".

If there is an issue, chances are you will get a more complete error message that way (through the command-line interface '`cleartool`', rather than relying on GUI error messages)

Comment: Thanks for that info. I think the problem is when I created a component it didn't create a initial baseline automatically and I couldn't rebase the integration stream that's why it is not displaying the foundation baseline. (cleartool lsstream -l spider1_wells_integration@/spider1_pvob) didn't display any baselines. In this case how can I create a baseline in component level and rebase the integration stream with that particular baseline?

Comment: @user2370590 a component you just created has an "`_INITIAL`" baseline (as described in http://stackoverflow.com/a/3238184/6309). You can rebase the integration stream against that initial baseline.

Comment: The issue is there is no _INITIAL baseline in my component. How can I make baseline on it?

Comment: @user2370590 there is one, as in *any* new UCM component created. It represents the component in its empty state: see http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21149500. It is named "`<COMPONENT NAME>_INITIAL`". See a practical example of a component creation in http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21152760.